# How to get text of an array of elements using Nightwatch?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I have an array of multiple elements and I need to check the inner text of each ones. It won't be a problem if I had only one element, because I would call element.getText() method on it. But I don't know what to do with an array of elements.

Here is my code :

```
        await browser.elements('css selector', '.myCSSClass', async function (elements) {
            console.log(elements.value)
            elements.value.forEach(function (element) {
                browser.elementIdText(element.ELEMENT, function (result) {
                    console.log(result)
                    console.log(result.value)
                })
            })
        })
```

Here is the result:

> Error
> First argument passed to .elementIdText() should be a web element ID string. Received undefined.
> See https://nightwatchjs.org/api/elementIdText.html

First console.log gives me the following array:

> [
> {
> 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '6A348CF895A32F15D11F5E5DE43F0B2D_element_78'
> },
> {
> 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '6A348CF895A32F15D11F5E5DE43F0B2D_element_79'
> }
> ]

What am I missing here ?

I tried using element.getText() and browser.elementIdText(). Same result.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.